# Print Array values in loop forever

Tags: javascript

I have Array and two buttons on UI. I want to print the Array value in a loop. I have set the default count to 7 mean on click on button 7 item would be sliced from Array and printed.

The logic I have written is getting the expected 7 item from Array but it does end when it reaches to end.

Button named `DOWN` will be getting last 7 value from the beginning of the Array.

and button 'UP' will be getting last 7 value from the back of the Array.

This is what I am getting right now by clicking on DOWN button.

[image]

expected result

[image]

It should run in never ending loop. It should keep repeating value.

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqbjd91L/6/)

```
var numberOfElement =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];

var howManyelement = 7;

var up = 0;
$('.up').click(function(){
  var start = numberOfElement.length - (up + howManyelement);

     console.log(numberOfElement.slice(start, numberOfElement.length - (up)));
   up+=howManyelement;
})

var down = 0;
$('.down').click(function(){
  var start = 0 + down;
     console.log(numberOfElement.slice(start, down + howManyelement));
   down+=howManyelement;

})
```

Comment: How can we help you if you don't show your code?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Apologize for not putting the code at first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
// Setup
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
var arrIndex = 0;

function getValues(length) {
    // Slice the array from our current index to the current index + the requested length
    var values = arr.slice(arrIndex, arrIndex + length);
    var valueCount = values.length;

    // Make sure we keep adding the length of values to arrIndex so we pull new values
    arrIndex += valueCount;

    if (valueCount < length) {
        arrIndex = 0;

        // Figure out how many extra values we need and add it to the returned values
        return values.concat( getValues(length - valueCount) );
    } else if (arrIndex >= arr.length) {
        // We have just printed the last item in the array - let's reset the index
        arrIndex = 0;
    }

    return values;
}

// Get the values
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log( getValues(7) );
}
```

Result:
[image: array]

Comment: Thanks, How to reverse this function to get value from back of array like [30,29,28...]

Comment: Simply deduct 7 from arrIndex and check if it's less than 0 - if it is then reset arrIndex to (arr.length - arrIndex) - then call `getValues` as shown.